# Intersect lines and polygons

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I am tring to intersect lines with a polygon grid, but i got an error when i run this:

```
create table "st11_01_vd" as 
  SELECT (
    "grid_1km.gid",
    "st11_012017_ln.linetime",
    ST_INTERSECTION("grid_1km.geom", "st11_012017_ln.geom") 
  FROM "grid_1km",
    "st11_012017_ln" 
  WHERE ST_Intersects("grid_1km.geom", "st11_012017_ln.geom");
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: a sintax error on "FROM"

Answer (score 3):

There is an open parentheses after the `select` statement that is never closed. It should be removed.

You should also separate table name from the column name. As it is, the column name is everything between the double quotes

```
create table "st11_01_vd" as 
  SELECT 
    "grid_1km"."gid",
    "st11_012017_ln"."linetime",
    ST_INTERSECTION("grid_1km"."geom", "st11_012017_ln"."geom") 
  FROM "grid_1km",
    "st11_012017_ln" 
  WHERE ST_Intersects("grid_1km"."geom", "st11_01207_ln"."geom");
```

Since you are not using any capital letter, do yourself a favor and just drop the doubles quotes..

```
create table st11_01_vd as
  SELECT 
    grid_1km.gid,
    st11_012017_ln.linetime,
    ST_INTERSECTION(grid_1km.geom, st11_012017_ln.geom) 
  FROM grid_1km,
    st11_012017_ln 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(grid_1km.geom, st11_01207_ln.geom);
```